# Вызвать функцию в setTimeout

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть такая функция:

```
var animateTitle = function(countMessages) {
}
```

Как ее повторно вызвать в  `setTimeout`? Что-то наподобие в теле самой функции (рекурсия):

```
setTimeout(animateTitle(call), 3000);
```

Только параметры как передать правильно? В моем примере вылетает ошибка в консоли:

> Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call
> stack size exceeded

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Скорее всего, вам лучше использовать не setTimeout, а setInterval.
Но если очень хочется, то так и вызывайте:

```
function animateTitle(countMessages) {
  setTimeout(function(){ animateTitle(call); }, 3000);
}
```

Только учтите, что-таки callstack у вас произойдет. Через 7000-49000 итераций.

Comment: @Oleg Ponomarchuk, вызывать функцию нужно в callback-е последнего действия.

Comment: @knes разве в данном случае setTimeout и setInterval не имеют критическую разницу? setTimeout не сделает интервала между вызовами, т.к. не останавливает исполнение подобно sleep в других языках.
Или сделает?

Comment: Паузу он не сделает. Он как бы создаст еще одну ветвь исполнения.
Т.е. если сама функция исполняется 4 секунды, у нас будет накапливаться куча исполняемых функций.

НО. Как правило, когда надо вызывать функцию из самой себя по таймауту, людям требуется либо таймер(setInterval), либо 

  >callback последнего действия.

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(animateTitle, 3000, call); // call - передаваемый параметр
```